# Why adding entities to collection does not add them in database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have `Movies` and `Actors` entity, when I am adding persisted Actors to Movie and save this Movie to database, I can see that those actors were connected to Movie.

```
    @Test
    public void createMovieWithActorsSuccessfully() {

        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setFirstName("jan");
        actor.setLastName("kowalski");
        actorRepository.save(actor);

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setName("Comedy");
        categoryRepository.save(category);

        Director director = new Director();
        director.setFirstName("wladyslaw");
        director.setLastName("kwiatkowski");
        directorRepository.save(director);

        User someOwner = new User();
        someOwner.setUsername("someOwner");
        someOwner.setPassword("dummyPassword");
        someOwner.setFirstName("jan");
        someOwner.setLastName("kowalski");
        userRepository.save(someOwner);

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setYearProduced(Year.of(2000));
        movie.setCategory(category);
        movie.setDirector(director);
        movie.setName("dummy movie");
        movie.setOwner(someOwner);
        movie.setCost(BigDecimal.valueOf(300f));
        movie.setDescription("movie for testing");

        movie.getActors().add(actor);
        movieRepository.save(movie);

        Optional<Movie> optionalFoundMovie = movieRepository.findById(movie.getId());
        assertTrue(optionalFoundMovie.isPresent());
        Movie foundMovie = optionalFoundMovie.get();
        assertEquals(1, foundMovie.getActors().size());

        List<Actor> actors = Utils.iterableToCollection(foundMovie.getActors(), ArrayList::new);

        assertTrue(actors.contains(actor));

        List<Movie> movies = Utils.iterableToCollection(actors.get(0).getMovies(), ArrayList::new);
        assertEquals(1, movies.size());
        assertTrue(movies.contains(foundMovie));
    }
```

In above test when I find movie, it has actor in collection and this actor has this movie in it's own collection.

`Movie` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Movie extends Product {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER /*,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}*/)
    @JoinTable(name = "MOVIE_ACTOR",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id")
    )
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`Actor` entity:

```
public class Actor extends Person {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER /*, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}*/)
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

/*
    public void add(Movie m) {
        m.getActors().add(this);
        movies.add(m);
    }
*/
}
```

When I add movies to actor and save him to database, and the I find him by id, found actor movies collection is empty.

```
    @Test
    public void actorAddedToMoviesSuccessfully() {

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setYearProduced(Year.of(2000));
        movie.setCategory(category);
        movie.setDirector(director);
        movie.setName("dummy movie");
        movie.setOwner(someOwner);
        movie.setCost(BigDecimal.valueOf(300f));
        movie.setDescription("movie for testing");
        movieRepository.save(movie);

        Movie movie2 = new Movie();
        movie2.setYearProduced(Year.of(2003));
        movie2.setCategory(category);
        movie2.setDirector(director);
        movie2.setName("dummy movie2");
        movie2.setOwner(someOwner);
        movie2.setCost(BigDecimal.valueOf(300f));
        movie2.setDescription("movie for testing");
        movieRepository.save(movie2);

        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setFirstName("jan");
        actor.setLastName("kowalski");

        actor.add(movie);
        actor.add(movie2);

        actorRepository.save(actor);

        Actor foundActor = actorRepository.findById(actor.getId()).get();

        assertEquals(2, foundActor.getMovies().size()); // asserion error

        foundActor.getMovies().forEach(m -> assertTrue(m.getActors().contains(foundActor)));
/*
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
*/
```

How can I add movies to my actor? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you please remove "fetch = FetchType.EAGER" , and give it a try

Comment: You can collect the Actor returned from actorRepository.save. Also, couple of points to check - 1. Is it a save and retrieve in the same transaction ? Is READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level set ? 2. What is the cascade type between the entities ?

Comment: Why the cascade is commented in the example?  ```/*,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,  ...}*/``` ? Try using ```CascadeType.ALL```.